# In PowerBuilder, can I use an object as part of my menu?

Tags: object, menu, menuitem, powerbuilder

Is it possible with menus 4 layers deep to set up a link to another menu? If I made the menu 2 layers deep and then set the link at the end to another menu (or to an object), it would be easier to keep track of when making modifications.

(The 4-layers deep menu was not my idea!)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The method used in the right-click event to show popup menus might work:

lm_popup = Create m_mymenu
lm_popup.m_popup.PopMenu(this.PointerX(), this.PointerY())
Destroy lm_popup

Comment: _Ingenious!_ I'll start with that one, and many thanks. I'm still open to other ideas though - just in case.

Comment: I'm having no luck with this one actually. I mean the menus at the top of the Powerbuilder screen, under type 'menu'. Help appreciated anyway though.